# Unable to add members to Google Workspace Group

Tags: member, workspace, group

I am trying to add members to a group that I have created in google workspace. however since yesterday I am getting an error that something went wrong. nothing else is mentioned and I am unable to add members to groups. How do i go about resolving this?

[Screenshot of the error that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avErq.png)

I have already tried removing the group, creating a new one, logout and login, etc but nothing is working.